# Topology Bases and Real Numbers

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $\tau$, and for every $U$ in $\tau$ and every $x$ in $U$ there exists a $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \subseteq U$.

(1) Prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is a base on $X$.

(2) Prove that the topology generated by $\mathcal{C}$ is $\tau$.

(3) Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows: $(x_1,y_1) < (x_2, y_2)$ if $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$ (the dictionary order). For each $(x_1, y_1) < (x_2, y_2)$, define $B((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x_1, y_1) < (x,y) < (x_2, y_2)\}$
, and let

$\mathcal{B} = {B((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2)): (x_1,y_1) < (x_2,y_2)}$

Then $\mathcal{B}$ generates a topology $\tau_b$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. For each $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and each $c < d$, let $C(a,(c,d)) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (a,c) < (x,y) < (a,d)\}$, and let 
$\mathcal{C} = \{C(a,(c,d)): a,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, c<d \}$

Prove that $\mathcal{C}$ generates the same topology as $\mathcal{B}$.

I understand #1, half understand #2. and am so lost on #3 I dont know where to begin, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: can you see "intuitively" what the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are? one is contained in the other, so the topology generated by the bigger one will contain the topology generated by the smaller one. on the other hand, every element of the bigger one can be written as the union of some elements of the smaller one. hope that helps :)